# RBAC with Neo4J, in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, neo4j, rbac

We are using Neo4J, to store the users information who are logging into our website. The Roles, Permissions, Privileges are stored in the Database.
I would like to know if there is a good implementation of RBAC, written in NodeJS with Neo4J as the database.

I could see one for Graph ACL, and nothing much for RBAC : [Graph ACL](https://github.com/ydigital-factory/node-graph-acl%20Graph%20ACL)

Any experience in this would be useful for us to proceed further.

Comment: You can try Node-Casbin: https://github.com/casbin/node-casbin

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty well thought out graphgist for access control graphs here: https://neo4j.com/graphgist/06bbc73b-80e9-45fc-a1d6-c0270745ddfb

You'll have to apply the nomenclature of RBAC to what's provided (eg, groups in this graph look a lot like roles.) And the actual nodejs implementation isn't even kind of trivial so I can't be of any help there.